# DataGridView validate user input

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview, decimal

I have a DataGridView which is filled with object values this way:

```
POI_grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
POI_grid.DataSource = pois; //pois is an object generated from a class
```

I would like the user to edit some of the cells in this grid but there is some validation that needs to happen..

I currently validate user input using txt boxes and I was asked to do it in a GridView for simplicity. The way I validate user input is this:
(I validate if user entered decimal numbers only)

```
private void txt_X_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (((e.KeyChar < 48 || e.KeyChar > 57) && e.KeyChar != 8 && e.KeyChar != '.' && e.KeyChar != '-'))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '.')
    {
        if ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf(e.KeyChar) != -1)
            e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (e.KeyChar == '-' && (sender as TextBox).SelectionStart > 0)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

What's the best method to validate user input the same way I do it in text boxes but in a DataGridView?

So far, I've tried this following Rami suggestion:

```
 private void POI_grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal por_x;
            por_x = Convert.ToDecimal(POI_grid.CurrentCell.Value);

        }
```

of course I will need to add a try catch statement there to avoid issues but whenever possible, I'd like to restrict the user as he types into the cell, just like I do in the textbox..

SOLUTION:

Here's how I solved it:

```
private void POI_grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal por_x;
            try
            {
                por_x = Convert.ToDecimal(POI_grid.CurrentCell.Value);
            }
            catch
            {

               POI_grid.CurrentCell.Value= "0";
            }


        }

        private void POI_grid_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception is FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar números decimales solamente", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifique el formato del número ingresado", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced such problem but at the end i didn't find a method to prevent the user to type  a non-number charterer so I used `CellEndEdit event` to validate the input 
and if it's not valid it shows message box (only numbers are valid) and reset the cell to 0 .
and I hope that was useful for you  .

Comment: Hi Rami, can you share your code? I found the CellEndEdit event but not sure how you validated the entry. Thank you

Comment: `private: System::Void metroGrid19_CellEndEdit(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::DataGridViewCellEventArgs^  e) {
    try{
     Convert::ToDouble( metroGrid19->Rows[e->RowIndex]->Cells[e->ColumnIndex]->Value->ToString());

    }
    catch(...){
     metroGrid19->Rows[e->RowIndex]->Cells[e->ColumnIndex]->Value = "0" ;
    }
    metroButton11->Enabled = 1;
   }`

Comment: that's in c++ just replace the -> in . and don't catch any exception you have to catch a specfic one

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I solved it:

```
private void POI_grid_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            decimal por_x;
            try
            {
                por_x = Convert.ToDecimal(POI_grid.CurrentCell.Value);
            }
            catch
            {

               POI_grid.CurrentCell.Value= "0";
            }


        }

        private void POI_grid_DataError(object sender, DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Exception is FormatException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Debe ingresar números decimales solamente", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifique el formato del número ingresado", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
```